# Difference between arr[0]++ and ++arr[0]

Tags: c#, arrays, post-increment, pre-increment

In C#, is there a difference between the code (all in one statement, not part of a larger one) `arr[0]++;` and `++arr[0];`

<s>I fully understand, that in C / C++ / Objective-C, that this would not do the same thing, first case would get the value at arr's 0th index and increment that value by one, while the second one, increases the pointer value of arr, and does nothing to it's 0th position (same as `arr[1]; arr++;`).</s>

Thanks to sth, he has reminded me that this is the same in C# and C / C++ / Obj-C.

However, is there a difference between the two statements in C#?

Comment: the same difference as `val++` and `++val`.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to make sure that there wasn't some kind of difference like there is in C/C++/Obj-C... I'm parinoid :)

Comment: It is exactly the same as C/C++/etc. The same difference.

Comment: But doesn't the `++` operator have more precedence than the indexing operator in those languages?

Comment: Prefix `++` has lower precedence than `[]` array subscripts in C and C++, so there it also modifies the value in the array, not `arr` itself. (see for example http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/operator_precedence)

Comment: Oh yes, I was wrong on that too, thanks for reminding me of that, could be useful in the future :)

Comment: So many questions about this recently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`arr[0]++` returns the value of the first element of `arr`, then increments it.

`++arr[0]` increments the value of the first element of `arr`, then returns it

The difference only matters if you're using this as part of a longer instruction. For instance :

```
arr[0] = 42;
int x = arr[0]++; // x is now 42, arr[0] is now 43
```

Is not the same as:

```
arr[0] = 42;
int x = ++arr[0]; // x is now 43, arr[0] is now 43
```

Comment: Yes, but that means  that there is no difference if it is a singe statement, right?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a *single statement* there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

++x increments and then returns while x++ returns the value of x and then increments !
But if there is no one to receive the value, its all the same.

Answer (score 0):

An optimizing compiler should generate the same code if that statement exists by itself, but when you're using the value you're modifying inline, post-increment can require making a copy (so you can work with the old value), which can be expensive if the array is of a type that has an expensive copy constructor.